# can yijl=max(xijk+xilk-1) (k is between 0 and n) be written as a linear constraint?

Tags: java, max, cplex

my question is about

How can I write yijl=max(xijk+xilk-1) as a linear constraint in cplex java?
yijl, xilk and xijk are binary variables

Comment: This question is very broad, could you please narrow it down?

Comment: I have a constraint that states that the value of a binary decision variable (yijl) is given by the maximum of (xijk+xilk-1) where k varies from 0 to n and xijk and xilk are binary variables

Comment: can anyone help me!

Comment: StackOverflow community will be able to help you if the question is:  1.  specific and asked well, 2. formatted with code samples.    Refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `max` is over k, you need to add `n` additional constraints:

`yijl >= xijk+xilk-1      for every k`

i.e.

`y_ijl >= xij0+xil0-1
y_ijl >= xij1+xil1-1
...
y_ijl >= xijn+xiln-1`

**Update**

The requirement is `xijk=xilk=1 for every k then yijl=1 and 0 otherwise`.

Assuming minimization problem, in case of two variables: if x1 and x2 are both 1 then y is 1 and 0 otherwise; it can be handled as follows:

`2*y >= x1 + x2 - 1
y, x1, x2, are {0,1}`

If x1=x2=1 then y is bounded to be 1.

Now, when we have 2(n+1) variables:

`2*(n+1)*y_ijl >= sum_k (x_ijk+x_ilk) - 2*(n+1)-1`

Comment: I did that at the beginning. But since yijl are binary variables too. The program will give me yij=1 for all the cases

Comment: Can you explain in words, why do you need yijl=max(xijk+xilk-1) constraint after all? what is it supposed to mean? may be there is another way to model your requirements

Comment: yijl=1 if xijk=xijk=1 and yijl=0 otherwise

Comment: Do you mean: if xijk=xilk=1 for every k then yijl=1 and 0 otherwise?

Comment: yes if xijk=xilk=1 for every k then yijl=1 and 0 otherwise?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However, your answer doesn't fit my requirement. xijk=1only for one value of k. It is equal zero otherwise

Comment: Thus, sum_k (x_ijk+x_ilk)=2 or 1 or 0